# Cannot set ItemsSource for XamComboEditor in a XamDataGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I need to display in a `XamDataGrid` data coming from a class that contains a few properties and a list of valid choices from one of them. Something like:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public string Identifier {get;private set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public IEnumeranble<string> ValidValues {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to set the setup the `XamDataGrid` so that I have a non editable `Identifier` column and a `Value` column editable via a `XamComboEditor`. This is the xaml I came up to:

```
    <igDP:XamDataGrid GroupByAreaLocation="None">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout>
                <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    <igDP:Field Name="Identifier"/>
                    <igDP:Field Name="Value">
                        <igDP:Field.Settings>
                            <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
                                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.DataItem.Values, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                        </igDP:Field.Settings>
                    </igDP:Field>
                </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

The data binding on the `XamDataGrid` works fine but the one on the `XamComboEditor.ItemsSource` does not work but I am not sure how I could fix id. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an alternative way to do it using events.

In XAML I had to specify those settings instead of what I had:

```
                            <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                        <Style.Setters>
                                            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="XCEloaded"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False" />
                                        </Style.Setters>
                                    </Style>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
```

And I handled the event with this piece of code:

```
    private void XCEloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var drp = Utilities.GetAncestorFromType(sender as DependencyObject, typeof(DataRecordPresenter), true) as DataRecordPresenter;
        if (drp.DataRecord.DataItem != null)
            (sender as XamComboEditor).ItemsSource = (drp.DataRecord.DataItem as DataViewModel).ValidValues;
    }
```

It doesn't look like the cleanest solution but at least it works.